# JavaScript for each element in <ul>

Tags: javascript, list

How can I go through a certain ul-Element and search every li-Element in it? I've only found jquery solutions, but don't want to use it here.

Comment: `<element>.getElementsByTagName` is the tool you need here.

Comment: Or `<element>.querySelectorAll`. You'd probably profit the most from reading a tutorial about DOM + JS: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: @FelixKling querySelectorAll doesn't work with older browsers, so I think I have to loop through the elements.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is supported in IE8+. If you have to support IE7 and below, then yes, you have to use `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through a selection without some external library such as jQuery or D3 is kind of annoying because the selection will not return an *Array* but instead an *HTMLCollection* or *NodeList* (depending on your browser).  I recommend using some third party library if you are doing this sort of thing often.  Anyway here's how to do it in pure JavaScript.

```
// This is not an Array but either an HTMLCollection or a NodeList
var selection = document.getElementById(<id>).getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
{
    // do something with selection[i]
}
```

It is important to note that because your selection is not an Array you cannot use *for-each* loops (the intended way at least) or any higher level *Array* functions as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).